# Non-singular matrices - properties

Tags: matrices, self-learning

Let $K=AA'$ where $A'$ is the transpose of $A$. $A$ is non-singular. Prove that $K\gt0$, or that all elements in $K$ are strictly non-zero. Not sure where to begin with this. I know that if $A$ is non-singular (invertible), its transpose is also invertible, however I'm not sure where the condition of strictly positive is coming from.

Comment: I think that you are meant to prove that $K$ is positive definite rather than prove that $K$ has strictly non-zero entries, which isn't generally true.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample, to the question as stated:

Take 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-1\\0&1}\\
AA' = \pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&1}
$$